# Get exact size of text on a canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I hope there is someone out there to help me with this:
I need to get the exact size of a text. Just measuring a span or so not precise enough for my purposes.

Right now, I am using a canvas to find the non-transparent pixels in the canvas.
This is my code:

```js
// a function to draw the text on the canvas

let text = "Hello World";
let canvas = document.getElementById('happy-canvas');
let width = 1000
let height = 100
canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.font = "30px cursive";
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 60);

  // get the image data
  let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data,
    first = false,
    last = false,
    r = height,
    c = 0

  // get the width of the text and convert it to an integer
  const canvWidth = parseInt(ctx.measureText(text).width)

  //Find the last line with a non-transparent pixel
  while (!last && r) {
    r--
    for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
      if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
        last = r
        break
      }
    }
  }

  let canvasHeight = 0
  // Find the first line with a non-transparent pixel
  while (r) {
    r--
    for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
      if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
        first = r
        break
      }
    }

    canvasHeight = last - first
  }

  //draw a rectangle around the text
  ctx.strokeRect(0, first, canvWidth, canvasHeight)
```

```html
<div> The last "d" is not completely inside of the the box
  <canvas id="happy-canvas" width="150" height="150"> I wonder what is here</canvas>
</div>
```

This works to get the exact height of the text, but not the width.
So I use "measureText" right now, but that function gets different sizes depending on the browser and on the font I use.
If I use a reagular font, it works quite well. But if I use a more playful font, it does not work at all.

Here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nz5h.png

The black box is the measured size. And as you can see "measureText" does not get the correct width.
Right now I am out of any idea, what else I could do.

Comment: I made a snippet of you code, can you update it with a working example?

Comment: What is font in ` if (font.capitalize) `

Comment: You can ignore `if (font.capitalize)`. It is irrelevant for the example. The above code snippet is now a working example. The font for the canvas is "cursive" and the last "d" of "Hello World" is not completely inside the box.

Comment: You need to check in Firefox, as Chrome seems not to support the font "cursive". In Firefox it works though.

Comment: @pixelbash I know you said 'This works to get the exact height of the text' but I wouldn't know why your method for detecting non-transparent rows shouldn't work for columns. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @obscure It works differently for columns. But just 2min ago, I managed to get it working. I had to dig a bit deeper intro the matter on how `getImageData()` actually works. I will post my solution in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just got it working.

What am I doing?
Well, in my case I know, that the text will always start at a x-value of 0.
The length of the text is therefore the non-transparent pixel with the highest x-value in the array given by `getImageData()`.
So I am looping through the `getImageData()`-array. If I find a pixel that has a higher alpha-value than 0, I will save its x and y value into `highestPixel`. The next time I find a pixel, I will check if its x-value is higher as the one that is currently in `highestPixel`. If so, I will overwrite `highestPixel` with the new values. At the end, I return `highestPixel` and its x-value will be the exact length of the text.

Here is the code:

```js
// a function to draw the text on the canvas

let text = "Hello World";
let canvas = document.getElementById('happy-canvas');
let width = 1000
let height = 100
canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.font = "30px cursive";
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 60);

// get the image data
let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data,
  first = false,
  last = false,
  r = height,
  c = 0

// get the width of the text and convert it to an integer
let getPixelwithHighestX = () => {
  let xOfPixel = 0
  let yOfPixel = 0
  let highestPixel = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
  for (let i = 3; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if (data[i] !== 0) {
      yOfPixel = Math.floor(i / 4 / width)
      xOfPixel = Math.floor(i / 4) - yOfPixel * width
      if (xOfPixel > highestPixel.x) {
        highestPixel.x = xOfPixel
        highestPixel.y = yOfPixel
      }
    }
  }
  return highestPixel
}

let hightestPixel = getPixelwithHighestX()

//Find the last line with a non-transparent pixel
while (!last && r) {
  r--
  for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
    if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
      last = r
      break
    }
  }
}

let canvasHeight = 0
// Find the first line with a non-transparent pixel
while (r) {
  r--
  for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
    if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
      first = r
      break
    }
  }

  canvasHeight = last - first
}

//draw a rectangle around the text
ctx.strokeRect(0, first, hightestPixel.x, canvasHeight)
```

```html
<div> The text is now completely inside the box
  <canvas id="happy-canvas" width="150" height="150"> I wonder what is here</canvas>
</div>
```